# Having trouble configuring static IPs to PODs attached with MACVLAN interface

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, cni, macvlan

Here is the scenario.
There is a deployment set through which 2 PODs are created. I am attaching a MACVLAN interface to these PODs for external communication.

Macvlan definition

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: test-macvlandef01
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "name": "test-macvlandef01",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "whereabouts",
        "datastore": "kubernetes",
        "kubernetes": { "kubeconfig": "/etc/cni/net.d/whereabouts.d/whereabouts.kubeconfig" },
        "range": "192.168.0.0/24",
        "range_start": "192.168.0.44",
        "range_end": "192.168.0.45"
      }
    }'
```

Deployment Set

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: centos-test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: centos
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: centos
      annotations:
       k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: "test-macvlandef01"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        test: "true"
      containers:
      - name: centos
        image: centos
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 100000" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Result. Both PODs have IPs from the allocated pool.

```
[master1 ~]# kubectl exec -it centos-test-64f8fbf47f-wrjr7  ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0@if61: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:ef:ca:2c:31:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.20.14.176/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: net1@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 52:2f:bd:f9:03:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.44/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global net1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       
[master1 ~]# kubectl exec -it centos-test-64f8fbf47f-vtkst  ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0@if60: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ae:e6:4e:95:2a:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.20.14.175/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: net1@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:fb:b5:90:d0:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.45/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global net1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now what I need to configure is, a bigger allocation pool in macvlan definition file, but have only specific 2 IPs to be assigned to the PODs.
I tried below configuration.

Macvlan definition

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: test-macvlandef01
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "name": "test-macvlandef01",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "whereabouts",
        "datastore": "kubernetes",
        "kubernetes": { "kubeconfig": "/etc/cni/net.d/whereabouts.d/whereabouts.kubeconfig" },
        "range": "192.168.0.0/24",
        "range_start": "192.168.0.40",
        "range_end": "192.168.0.50"
      }
    }'
```

Deployment Set

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: centos-test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: centos
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: centos
      annotations:
       k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '[{ "name": "test-macvlandef01","ips": "192.168.0.44"},{"name": "test-macvlandef01","ips": "192.168.0.45"}]'
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        test: "true"
      containers:
      - name: centos
        image: centos
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 100000" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

PODs are coming up without MACVLAN interface and also I see no error associated with the POD.

```
[master1 ~]# kubectl exec -it centos-test-b59db89f7-2vvqx  ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0@if65: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 62:31:fc:64:8f:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.20.14.180/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[master1 ~]# kubectl exec -it centos-test-b59db89f7-6c75h  ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0@if64: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether e6:23:30:ff:bf:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.20.14.179/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Please suggest any modifications or additions that would help with the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please describe your environment in more details? What kind of cluster do you have, cloud or on-premise nodes, Kubernetes/Openshift version, etc. What CNI and what plugins did you install and how exactly? Did you use any guides/manuals to configure MACVLAN?

Answer (score 0):

I want to pay your attention into 2 points below. Partial answer.

---

1. From your post I see that you want to use special IP addresses. To use such functionality, according to  [Extention convention from CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/blob/master/CONVENTIONS.md#dynamic-plugin-specific-fields-capabilities--runtime-configuration) you may need to use `"capabilities":  {"ips":  true}` capability in your Macvlan definition. Something like this:

```yaml
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "name": "test-macvlandef01",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "capabilities": {"ips": true}
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "bridge",
```

You can also find good explanation with examples  in [Attaching a pod to an additional network](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/networking/multiple_networks/attaching-pod.html#nw-multus-advanced-annotations_attaching-pod) documentation.

[image: macvlan_plugin]

---

2. I suppose that you use [whereabouts plugin](https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/whereabouts), since `"type":  "whereabouts"` presents in your Macvlan definition. It supports exclusions:

> You can also specify ranges to exclude from assignment, so if for
> example you'd like to assign IP addresses within the range
> `192.168.2.0/24`, you can exclude IP addresses within it by adding
> them to an exclude list. For example, if you decide to exclude the
> range `192.168.2.0/28`, the first IP address assigned in the range
> will be `192.168.2.16`.

Knowing this fact, you can specify ranges of IPs to exclude from your configuration in accordance with [Whereabouts IPAM Config example](https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/whereabouts#example-ipam-config). Try to add `exclude` field in Macvlan definition with necessary IPs/subnets, which should be excluded.
Possible solution for your particular case:

```yaml
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "name": "test-macvlandef01",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "capabilities": {"ips": true}
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "whereabouts",
        "range": "192.168.0.0/24",
        "range_start": "192.168.0.40",
        "range_end": "192.168.0.50"
        "exclude": [
           "192.168.0.40/32",
           "192.168.0.41/32",
           ...
        ]
      }
  }'
```

Comment: hi @andrew,
i tried with with "capabilities":  {"ips":  true}" , but got the same result. POD is up but IP is not assigned

Comment: Hello @Ravi Pillai. Did you try the second option with Exclude field?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Excluding is not an option for me as the requirement is to have a macvlan definition with, for example, 30 IPs and use the same for multiple deployments with each deployment having their own set of static IPs.

Comment: Ok, @Ravi Pillai. Could you please provide information about your infrastructure - are you using only Macvlan interface or Macvlan and Whereabouts plugin together? I can see information about Whereabouts plugin only from your code, but not in your question.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I am open to not using whereabouts also. Only need to satisfy the use case.